# Caching problem

Tags: iis, caching

I have a web page with a set of images and java script files.

I want to cache all the images+java script other than a single image which is the logo.

Is this possible ? and how would I do it ?

I am using IIS server.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Just configure your server to have a default cache configuration for images and JS, and then override it for the logo. Possibly with a `<file>` block if you are using Apache.

See this [decent caching tutorial](http://www.mnot.net/cache_docs/).